# How to remove the time and Display the Date only in RDLC

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

all I am using Winform(C#) and RDLC MySQL. In that I try to show the date only in Tablex.

But this date format have time also. How to remove the time.

My Expression is,..

```
=Fields!date.Value
```

See my report below.

[image]

Thanks in advance?

I am tried =Fields!date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") in expression But It through error,..
Error   1   An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'

Comment: I think you can specify a cell format.

Comment: @todda.speot.is Thanks. But how i specify?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [FormatDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatdatetime.aspx) method:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!date.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Or you can set the formatting in the properties window:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

="Current Date:-"&Format(Now,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt")
this is for current date and time

Comment: Can you elaborate on our answer and explain why yours is better than the ones already provided?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
=FormatDateTime(Now(), DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!dtStamp.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

The image shows the working of dateFormat.

[image: The image shows the working of dateFormat]

Answer (score -1):

formate(Fields!date.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")