# RDLC Report date display wrongly

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

Hi I got the date field and need to display dd-MMM-yyyy but it display wrongly by switching the month and day

ASP.NET

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-04-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

RLDC Report

```
=Format(Cdate(First(Fields!DOB.Value, "SIDocument_iLifeLead")),"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Final Output: 04-Aug-2015 it should be 08-Apr-2015

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Buddy ,please try with this.I got the output as you needed

**=CDate(Fields!DOB.Value).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")**

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FormatDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatdatetime.aspx) method.
May this link helps you,
[stackoverflow.com/questions/9140630](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140630/how-to-remove-the-time-and-display-the-date-only-in-rdlc)